# Im(z) and Re(z) of $\bar z^2+ \frac {1}{z^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Given:
$\bar z^2+ \frac {1}{z^2}$, $z \in \mathbb{C}, z \neq 0$

Task:
Determine Im(z) and Re(z).

So my approach:
$$\bar z^2+ \frac {1}{z^2} = \bar z^2+ \frac {\bar z^2}{(z \bar z)^2} = \frac {\bar z^2(z \bar z)^2}{(z \bar z)^2}+\frac {\bar z^2}{(z \bar z)^2} = \frac {\bar z^2 + \bar z(z \bar z)^2}{(z \bar z)^2}$$

Since z is a complex number it´s of the shape $z = x + iy$, but if I insert this definition, the hole calculation becomes a huges mess. Does anyone see an easier way to solve this problem?

Comment: What are you given? The specific complex value of $\bar z^2 + \dfrac 1{z^2}$?

Comment: It is a bit of a mess, but the final answer is a bit of a mess too. There's no way for you to avoid the mess. I guess I'd just point out that wherever you have $(z\overline{z})^2$, you can replace it with $(x^2 + y^2)^2$, which is a real number. Maybe you'd find it easier to deal with $\frac{\overline{z}^2 + k\overline{z}}{k}$ where $k$ is a real number? You can then substitute $k = (x^2 + y^2)^2$ at the end.

Comment: Thanks Bendit, this helped me a lot <3

Comment: @Fixi68ssdff846 The question does not specify in what form the answer must be. You could avoid cartesian altogether, unless specifically required: $\;\bar z^2+ \frac {1}{z^2}=\bar z^2 \cdot \left(1 + \frac{1}{|z|^4}\right)$ where $\,\left(1 + \frac{1}{|z|^4}\right) \in \mathbb R\,$, so $\,\text{Re}\left(\bar z^2+ \frac {1}{z^2}\right)=\text{Re}\left(\bar z^2\right) \cdot \left(1 + \frac{1}{|z|^4}\right)=\text{Re}\left( z^2\right) \cdot \left(1 + \frac{1}{|z|^4}\right)\,$, and similar for $\,\text{Im}(\dots)\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right track for finding the Im and Re of $\bar z^2+ \frac {1}{z^2}$. Just note that $z\bar z=x^2+y^2\in \mathbb R$ and this simplifies your calculations hugely.

Comment: Well thx, in this case there is no "easier" way .D

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume $z=re^{i\varphi}$. We have then
$$ \bar{z}^2 + \frac{1}{z^2} = e^{-2i\varphi} (r^2+ \frac{1}{r^2})$$
Knwing $\bar{z}^2 + \frac{1}{z^2}$ you can find its module and argument, and from them you can calculate $r$ and $\varphi$ respectively. Then you have ${\rm Im}(z) = r\sin\varphi$ and ${\rm Re}(z) = r\cos\varphi$.

Answer (score 1):

You are given $\bar z^2 +1/z^2$ and need to find $z$. Write $z$ as $\rho(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$, $\rho$ is the length, $\theta$ is the argument, both to be found. Then $\bar z=\rho(\cos\theta-i\sin\theta)$, $\bar z^2=\rho^2(\cos2\theta -i\sin2\theta)$,
$$\bar z^2+1/z^2=\rho^2(\cos2\theta -i\sin2\theta)+1/(\rho^2)(\cos(2\theta)-i\sin(2\theta)))=(\rho^2+1/\rho^2)(\cos2\theta-i\sin2\theta).$$ So the length of $\bar z^2 +1/z^2$ is $\rho^2+1/\rho^2$ from which you find $\rho$ and the argument of  $\bar z^2 +1/z^2$ is $-2\theta$ which gives $\theta$. This determines $z$.